# Convert path to list

Tags: python

I have a path made of directories (e.g. `'grandpa\\parent\\child'`) that I need to transform in a list (e.g. `['grandpa', 'parent', 'child']`).

The path can have less or more subdirectories (e.g. `['parent', 'child']`).

I tried iterating [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) but it doesn't work well in all circumstances:

```py
import os

s = []
def splitall(path):
    l = list(os.path.split(path))
    s.append(l[1])
    return s if l[0] == '' else splitall(l[0])

p = 'grandpa\\parent\\child'
l = splitall(p)
print(l)
```

There should be a better way, right? Maybe a method that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Does using `your_list.split('\\')` handle all the cases you need?

Comment: Why doesn't `os.path.split()` work well? When does it fail?

Comment: Perhaps `os.walk()` could be useful in developing your program? Documentation is at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: @Barmar it fails inside a for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib%20parts#pathlib.PurePath.parts) too.

```
import pathlib

path = "a\\b\\c"
p = pathlib.Path(path)
result = p.parts
```

Comment: pathlib is great and OS agnostic - removing my answer for this

Comment: That said: it seems unlikely you actually need this -- are you sure this isn't an [XY problem?](http://xyproblem.info)